# Does ,,sich beschäftigen um jn." sound natural to native speakers?

Tags: collocation

Is *sich beschäftigen um jn.* in the sense *occupy oneself with looking after sb.* a natural expression to native speakers?

In standard dictionaries I find examples for the collocation *beschäftigt sein um jn.* but none for the pattern *sich beschäftigen um jn.*

Hence I am wondering whether it is sheer incident absence of examples or it reflects any intrinsic invalidity in the collocation of *sich beschäftigen* with *um jn.*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a native speaker, I do not recall hearing *sich um jn. beschäftigen*. I would suggest *sich um jn. kümmern* for the sense *look after sb.* with the implied meaning that this occupies oneself.

Also note *sich mit jm. beschäftigen*, meaning *to spend time on someone*, typically a dependent person, such as a child with the objective of education or an elderly person.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't sound natural at all. And I'd go as far as to suggest that any dictionary that lists

> beschäftigt sein um jn.

is in utter need of review.

To translate the meaning you're after in German you'd end up with something way more complex than that:

> sich damit beschäftigt halten, sich um jemanden zu kümmern.

Comment: The dictionary in question is the [online Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/beschaeftigen), BTW.

Comment: Tja, mit dem Duden geht's begab :/

Comment: Ich bin sicher, sie nehmen Dein Angebot zur Revision mit Begeisterung an.

Comment: Ich habe da so meine Zweifel. =D

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not sound natural, the common expression for that is `sich beschäftigen mit jemand`.

`Beschäftigt sein` means being busy.